# What do I need to fill at "// callback code" to get Mailcheck working? (jquery usage)

Tags: javascript, jquery

**SOLVED**

**Mailcheck uses the "on" method, which isn't available in the outdated version of JQuery that I was using. THANK YOU TO KUFI AND MARTIN.**

I'm a beginner at Javascript/Jquery, and I am stuck trying to get [this](https://github.com/Kicksend/mailcheck) to work.

I have a working form on my website, where I would like to add this client-side spell-check for popular email domains. The id of the text field for the email address is simply "Email", so I have made this little change (capital E).

So my code looks like this... with some test statements.

```
<script>
document.write("test0");
document.getElementById('testspan').innerHTML = 'test3';

var domains = ['hotmail.com', 'gmail.com', 'aol.com'];
$('#Email').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).mailcheck({
    domains: domains,   // optional

    suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
      // callback code
      document.getElementById('testspan').innerHTML = 'test4';
      document.write("test1");
    },

    empty: function(element) {
      // callback code
      document.write("test2");
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

The text "test0test3" does appear as expected, similar to what would happen if I did a PHP echo.

But nothing visibly happens when focus leaves the my email textbox.

I don't know if I have given enough detail for someone to identify where I've gone wrong...

I don't really understand what I am supposed to write in the place marked "//callback code". Do I need to manually provide the code that would make the "Did you mean ..." text appear as in their screenshot? [image]

**Thank you, Kufi and Martin.** 
I have followed Kufi's code, and also inserted

```
<span id="suggestedEmail"></span>
```

after the email text input element. But nothing happens. Could someone suggest a suitable test statement I can write inside the callback function to definitively find out whether the code path is being exercised or not. I have a feeling it isn't.

**UPDATE 3**

**Thank you again Kufi and Martin,**

I have not been able to get it to work, even after making a minimal .HTML file for testing... I feel that now, someone would be able to spot the error I have made.
Here is the entirety of my test file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Testing mailcheck</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mailcheck.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="contactus_mail.php">
 Name: <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30"  /> </br>
 Email: <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" />  <span id="suggestedEmail"></span> </br>
 Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="72" value="" /> </br>
 <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

</br>
<span id="testspan1"></span>
</br>
<span id="testspan2"></span>
</br>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#testspan1").html("test1");
$(function() {
var domains = ['hotmail.com', 'gmail.com', 'live.com', 'yahoo.com'];
 $("#email").on('blur', function() {
  $(this).mailcheck({
    domains: domains,   // optional
    suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
      // callback code
      $("#suggestedEmail").html("Did you mean " + suggestion.full);
    },
    empty: function(element) {
      // callback code
      document.write("empty was called");
    }
  });
 });
});
$("#testspan2").html("test2");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything I have to check besides the reachability of the two external JS files? Jquery versions?

**SOLVED!**

I was getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

at the line that looks like:

```
$("#email").on('blur', function() {
```

This went away when I switched from using JQuery 1.3.2 to the current 1.7.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it you have to write your own visual feedback as it is stated in their documentation:

"You can use the callbacks to display the appropriate visual feedback to the user." (Chapter "Usage" at the bottom).

So you need something like this to show the suggested email:

```
suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
    $("#suggestedEmail").html("Did you mean " + suggestion.full);
}
```

Edit:
To your updated question. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cgfR3/) is a working jsfiddle. If the posted javascriptcode is the actually used code you need to surround it with `$(function() { //your code here });`

This code should work:

```
$(function() {
    var domains = ['hotmail.com', 'gmail.com', 'aol.com'];
    $('#Email').on('blur', function() {
      $(this).mailcheck({
        domains: domains,   // optional

        suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
            $("#suggestedEmail").html("Did you mean " + suggestion.full);
        },
        empty: function(element) {
          document.write("test2");
        }
      });
    });
});
```

The `$(function() { ... });` needs to be used so that the code inside is is executed after the whole page has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks Kufi, I must have something else wrong with my code, because I suspect the suggested function isn't even being triggered. Any suggestions as to how to troubleshoot this? THANKS!

Comment: Hi Kufi, I see that your code is working on JSFiddle, thanks, but I still have not made things work on my server. I have posted the entire test HTML page I have made in "UPDATE 3" of my question, hope you can spot the error. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just made a breakthrough... I have put your JSFiddle code into a .HTML file on my server. And the console of my Chrome is saying: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'" about the line: "$('#Email').on('blur', function() {"

Comment: Your jquery-version is waaay to old. I don't know if they support the "on" in this version (but if I remember it right, they just added this functionality in one of the later versions). Try using the current version of it (Version 1.7.2)

Comment: Short update (can't edit my own comment). The function "on" was added in version 1.7 (according to the API-Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

Comment: Thanks! Problem was due to the old jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the "suggested" function takes in two parameters: **element** and **suggestion**. You should use the **suggestion** parameter to create the output as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: kufi beat me to it. :) Anyway, as his answer states, according to their documentation you should use **suggestion.full** to get the suggested email.

Comment: Thanks Martin, nothing happens when I tab away from the email input field, I suspect the callback function isn't being triggered at all, can you suggest some test code that can definitively check if the suggested function is being triggered? THANKS

Comment: If you're using Opera, Firefox, Chrome or the latest IE, try using `console.log (suggestion);` and open the browser's developer tools (e.g. FireBug for FF, Dragonfly for Opera) to see which action triggers the callback function. `console.log()` outputs the variable to the browser's console, so you should be able to see what gets passed as the `suggestion` parameter.

Comment: I have added the console.log line, (please see "UPDATE 3" in my question for entire test HTML file). Have I inserted it wrongly? Because I don't see any relevant activity in the JS console of my Chrome.

Comment: Oops, further tests showed that my console.log line was causing problems, probably did it wrong... anyway still can't get it to work after removing it.